# Jquery select all elements with tagname

Tags: jquery

I am adding a class on my dropdown, I have some dropdowns already with some class and some without any class.
I am adding class like this

```
$("select").addClass("myclass")
```

It is adding class, but if select have already a class it is not adding in that select 
eg in this select it is not adding myclass


Also this class abc is different for all select,so I can't write $(".abc").addClass()
How can I add class to all select just with tagname

Comment: This should work. whats wrong.

Comment: You are testing it wrong, this code should work. Now maybe you are calling it before all targeted SELECT elements are available in the DOM

Comment: Please show your HTML and JQuery code.

Comment: Are you trying to set the same class more than one time? I mean.. something like `$('select').addClass('myclass').addClass('myclass');` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a class to some elements by tagname with jQuery, use:

```
$('p').addClass('myclass');
```

If you want to add more than one class with different names, use:

```
$('p').addClass('myclass').addClass('myotherclass');
```

And if you want to add the same class more than one time, you can use:

```
$('p').addClass('myclass').attr('class', function(i, s){
    return s + ' myclass'; // returns value from class attribute and appends new value
});
```